# Why identifier 'strlen' is undefined?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, string-function

I am writing a program in C++. When I use the `strlen` function, it is underlined by a red line. Although the project is built without errors. This is how I use this function. (By the way, `strcpy` is also underlined).

```
Exception::Exception(int _Line, char* _File, char* _Func, char* _Desc)
{
  Line = _Line;
  int size = strlen(_File) + 1;
  File = new char[size];
  strcpy(File, _File);
  Func = new char[size];
  strcpy(Func, _Func);
  Desc = new char[size];
  strcpy(Desc, _Desc);
}
```

And I declared `<cstring>` library at the beginning of the file. Please tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you check the editor settings of your IDE?

Comment: @ArdentCoder No but what needs to be checked?

Comment: Why do you assume _Desc is the same length as _File?

Comment: I think you will have to produce a [mcve] along with the exact text of the error message.

Comment: `_Line`, `_File`, `_Func` and `_Desc` are identifiers that are reserved to the language implementation. By defining them in your own program, your program will have undefined behaviour. Use other names for your variabes.

Comment: @e7min *Re: "what needs to be checked?"* Tagging your IDE might help you.

Comment: ***When I use the strlen function, it is underlined by a red line. Although the project is built without errors.*** Intellisense is not perfect. It can have false positives. Something specific to your project must have caused Intellisense to fail in this way.

Comment: Ignore Intellisense and build.  Do you get any errors?  Also, if you edited any headers into your file or edited it externally Intellisense may not pick up on the changes.  Rescanning the file might help.  Right click in the editor window, pick the "Rescan" option, then "Rescan file".

Comment: It's hard to answer, since you haven't provided complete information as a [mcve]. You claim you have `#include <cstring>` but the code shown does not demonstrate that. There is probably something else missing from your preceding code but - since you haven't shown any proceeding code - nobody can guess what you may have left out, or how that interacts with Intellisense. One possibility is that your IDE is confused too, so (1)  Do a "build clean"  AND (2)  Rebuild the project from scratch. If that fails, add `using namespace std` after `#include <cstring>` and then clean and rebuild again.

Comment: @Peter This morning I started program again and it worked. Why it happens?

Comment: Could have required a rescan or clean build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system that underlines the code in the VS editor, called IntelliSense, does not use the same code as the compiler itself (or at least did not a few years ago when I used it last time). Sometimes it gets confused.

Try `std::strlen` instead, reorganizing the code, the includes, or something else.

Comment: I tried. He writes that namespace "std" has no member "strlen"

Comment: These feels more like a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 3):

As you can read up in the [documentation for `strlen()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen), `strlen()` is defined in `string.h` and the C++ counterpart `std::strlen()` is defined in `cstring`.

So to get rid of the error squiggles try adding one of the aforementioned headers.

```cpp
#include <cstring>
...
std::strlen()
```